# Open markdown file in python and store one line in variable

Tags: python

How can I copy a specific line (line 5 for example) from a markdown file to a variable?

```
read = open(path, 'r').read()
```

I'm assuming I can use this, but how can I access a specific line and assign it to a variable as a string?

```
line5 = ______
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the file text into a list using newline as a delimiter, retrieve the 5th list element (so the 4th index):

```
line5 = read.split("\n")[4]
```